# Images in RTF getting lost on Mac

Tags: objective-c, mono, monobjc

I have RTF text which I am showing to the user on Mac. Now I need to replace some text. The text has some images inline. When I execute the following code, the images are getting lost. I am using c#, Mono and Monobjc to run this on mac.

```
NSText _questionView;

// some initialisation code which I have skipped
//
NSRange range = NSRange.NSMakeRange(0, _questionView.TextStorage.Length);
NSData oldString = _questionView.RTFFromRange(range);
if (oldString != null)
{
   string s = oldString.ConvertRTFToString();
   _questionView.ReplaceCharactersInRangeWithRTF(range, s.ConvertToNSData());
   _questionView.SelectedRange = NSRange.NSMakeRange(0,0); 
   // After this line the inline images are lost.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing the images because you are converting the RTF content to `NSString`. `NSString` can only carry text, not attributes. You should consider using [NSAttributedString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/AttributedStrings.html) instead for the text manipulation, in order to keep the RTF attributes (style, images, etc.).